# How to format JSON data within controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

I'm new to AngularJS and JSON. I'm stuck in this stage where I want to filter unnecessary fields in the JSON.

I used code in my controller :

```
var data = $scope.choices; // Is an array
var datav = (JSON.stringify(data)); // array converted into a string need to be filtered
alert(datav);
```

If I `alert(datav)` am getting JSON data which mentioned below.

```
[{"title":"g","$$hashKey":"object:3"},{"id":"choice2","$$hashKey":"object:6","title":"ghgh"},{"id":"choice3","$$hashKey":"object:11","title":"fgh"}]
```

I want only "title" I don't want `$$hashKey` and `id`. How to do this?

Comment: what you tried so far? Did you tried https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?

Comment: use `.map()` to return only what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example).

When you first receive your array:

```
 const data = [
  {title: "hello" , "unwanted" : 34},
  {title: "hello" , "unwanted" : 35},
  {title: "hello" , "unwanted" : 36},
  {title: "hello" , "unwanted" : 37},

]



const wanted = data.map( d => {
  return {title: d.title}
});

console.log(wanted);
```

Comment: am gettin log as [undefined, undefined].

Comment: @PrashanthHarish my mistake, I made a slight syntax error. have a look at this [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/zazuzo/5/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `angular.toJson` instead of `JSON.stringify` which would omit `$$hashkey` for you.

> ## [`angular.toJson`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.toJson)
>
> Serializes input into a JSON-formatted string. Properties with leading $$ characters will be stripped since AngularJS uses this notation internally.

Like this,

```js
var myobj = [{
  "title": "g",
  "$$hashKey": "object:3"
}, {
  "id": "choice2",
  "$$hashKey": "object:6",
  "title": "ghgh"
}, {
  "id": "choice3",
  "$$hashKey": "object:11",
  "title": "fgh"
}]

console.log(angular.toJson(myobj))
console.log(JSON.stringify(myobj))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

**Edit**: In case you want to only show some property, use `Array.map` as described in other answers. `angular.toJson` would only be helpful *here* when you want to omit just `$$hashkey` retaining everything else.

Comment: @PrashanthHarish sure, I felt question a little misleading, will edit that for you. you can accept other suitable answer here

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to achieve what you want, and return only the properties you are interested in

```js
var data = [{"title":"g","$$hashKey":"object:3"},{"id":"choice2","$$hashKey":"object:6","title":"ghgh"},{"id":"choice3","$$hashKey":"object:11","title":"fgh"}];

var datav = data.map(d => ({title: d.title}));

console.log(datav)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```html
<html>
<head>
 <script Src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>

 <script>
  var app=angular.module("myapp", []);
  app.controller("namesctrl", function($scope){
            var data = [{"title":"g","$$hashKey":"object:3"},{"id":"choice2","$$hashKey":"object:6","title":"ghgh"},{"id":"choice3","$$hashKey":"object:11","title":"fgh"}];
            var data1 = data.map(d => ({title: d.title}));
            console.log(data1);
  });

  
 </script>


</head>
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="namesctrl">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is `str`?? make sure its an array.

Comment: so that's string na?? you stringified array to string.. now parse it then use `.map`

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = $scope.choices.map(function(index,item){
    return {id: item.id};
});
```

this is how you can map the desired object you need out of choices array

Comment: He asked for `title`, not for `id`

Comment: I gave him the idea behind the usage of map function, He can surely work out with what he needs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using a third party library. My guess is `Angular Material` which adds a similar `$$haskey` property to the dropdown array values. Ideally this shouldn't make any change to your array and you should still be able to get your properties on array object.

But if you specifficaly want to remove these unwanted properties you should create a new array out of this array using a `.map` function. Example:

```
var newArray= orginalArray.map(element => ({title: element.title}));
```

You can take out as many properties as you want and leave unwanted properties. Your new array is a complete different reference from old array.

Hope this helps